# How do I preserve folds in VIM when cutting and pasting?

Tags: vim

In vim, you can create a fold with zf, so if  is %, you can neatly fold a delimited block.

- is there a way to select some text in visual mode and automatically fold that?
- I've noticed that if I select a closed fold and use dd to delete it, then go somewhere else and use P to paste it, the fold will disappear and the fold will be expanded.  I want to cut the folded stuff and paste it and have it paste with the folds still intact and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can do the first if you use `:set foldmethod=manual` and then simply highlight the block you want and use <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to fold it.
- I don't think you can do this (at least, not without a script)

Answer (score 1):

Vim has several different fold strategies; I assume you are talking about manual folding.

Unfortunately, yanking and pasting does not keep the fold in-tact. You may be able to create a script that will re-fold pasted text, but it seems like it would be more annoying than useful in the end.